# Multiples arguments to NSOperation?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, nsinvocationoperation

I'm using NSOperationQueue in my app and i want to set multiples arguments to my operation how can i do that?

```
   NSOperationQueue *queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
   NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(methodCall) object:nil];
  [queue addOperation:operation];
  [operation release];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to create an array or dictionary with the data you need.

Ex:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDictionary *argumentDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:object1, @"Object1Key", object2, @"Object2Key", nil];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(methodCall:) object:argumentDictionary];
[queue addOperation:operation];
[operation release];
```

and in `- (void)methodCall:(NSDictionary *)argumentDictionary` you can use the objects and values stored in that dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Correct approach is to use NSInvocation
//create nsinvocation obj
SEL selector= @selector(methodName:);
NSMethodSignature * sig= [[self class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector: selector];
NSInvocation * invocation=[NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
[invocation setTarget: self];   
[invocation setSelector:selector];
[invocation setArgument:&firstArgument atIndex: 2];
[invocation setArgument:&secArgument atIndex: 3];
//operation with invocation
NSInvocationOperation* operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithInvocation:invocation];
[opQueue addOperation:operation];
```

Comment: This answer, even though it might be correct, is flagged as low quality because it is not clear enough.